A problem with geometry nodes for scattering objects
It seems like I made something dumb but for some reason using two geometry nodes for scattering objects give me the following result

The second node also distributes points on the scattered objects from the first node. This doesn't happen with me before, will appreciate any help.

It's not clear to me what's the problem and what you mean by "the second node" and "the first node". Could you elaborate? Cheers!

The second geometry node distributes objects on all faces, not only the plane (including the objects distributed by the first geometry node). If you focus on the image you will notice small objects distributed.

@MohamedObeid Well, of course it distributes points on all faces, not only the plane. You do not limit it to the plane in any way. Two successive modifiers build upon each other. The first modifier works on the base geometry, the second modifier works on the geometry created by the previous modifier. Or did I misunderstand the question?
